# Issues with Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I downloaded Android Studio and I have a folder named android-studio in my Downloads folder. I can launch it with

```
cd ~/Downloads/android-studio/bin
```

and then

```
./studio.sh
```

(It's strange, by the way, that I already have execute permissions on this file...)

Anyway, how can I add Android Studio to Dash, so that I can launch it as all the other apps? If I lock it to Launcher, and then try to open it from there, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select "Create desktop entry" from the menu on Welcome Dialog

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is this all I need, software-wise, to create Android apps? (apart from being able do do that, I mean...)

Comment: @A.N.Other you can have a look at this tutorial for getting started. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYKXDWkoIMUH088iBEr_B2WPfbPwtaG-V